# Exchanging try for if with and

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I get an error when I exchange

```
try:
    hrs=float(hrs)
    rate=float(rate):
```

to

```
if hrs=float(hrs) and rate=float(rate):
```

In other words:

1. is there an error in my use of `and`
2. is there a conceptual error in my code
3. can you not exchange `try` for `if`, (if you can, doesn't that make `try` redundant?)

Code:

```
hrs = raw_input('how many hours do you work per week:')
rate = raw_input('what is your rate per hour?:')
#try:
    #hrs=float(hrs)
    #rate=float(rate)
if (hrs == float(hrs) and rate == float(rate)):
    if (hrs > 40.0):
        pay=2*hrs*rate
        print ('your weekly salary is: %0.2f') %pay
    else: 
        pay = hrs*rate
        print('your weekly salary is: %0.2f') %pay
else:  
#except:
    print('enter a number, yo')
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, did you mean to compare for equality (`==`)? What precisely were you trying to achieve? *"is there a conceptual error in my code"* - probably.

Comment: Your could put the `float` on your `raw_input` and `try` around that.

Answer (score 2):

> 3) you cannot exchange try for if

It's that one. `try` and `if` do completely different jobs and have completely different syntax. They are not interchangeable.

`try` is for handling exceptions. The code block under the `try` is run unconditionally. If an exception is thrown in that code block, and the exception type matches one of the `except` blocks, then the exception stops propagating, and the associated `except` block is run to handle the exception.

`if` is for deciding whether to do one thing or another based on a condition. The expression on the `if` is evaluated, and if the expression has a true value, the code block under the `if` is executed. Otherwise, the block under the `else` is executed.

Exceptions and true/false conditions are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Others have touched on the problem with `=` vs `==` already.

But it's worth mentioning that python heavily relies on indentation to create meaning. The line `if hrs>40.0:` should be indented. Your first `else` statement does not have a corresponding `if` as your program currently exists.

Answer (score 0):

= is the assignment operator.

So in the try case, your code is confirming that indeed you can set 'hrs' to the value float(hrs) and this it runs just fine.

However hrs = float(hrs) is not a bool, so can't be used in an if statement.

```
 hrs == float(hrs)
```

will give you a true or false as appropriate and can be used in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the user enters text that validly represents two floats.  Then the `if` statement fails: since `raw_input` returns a string, `hrs` is originally bound to a string.  In the `if` statement, the `float` function returns a number (a float, of course); the expression `hrs == float(hrs)` raises an exception because you are trying to compare a number to a string.

Suppose the user enters some text that doesn't convert to a float.  Now the `if` statement fails for a different reason: an exception is raised by the `float` function when it can't convert the string.  That means that the float function doesn't return, and so the == comparison never is tried.  In neither case do you ever see the error message.

In the commented-out try:except version of the program, the exception is thrown within the try: block so the exception handler runs, and the error message prints.

What you want is something like this (a good case for using a `try:except:else:`)

```
str_hrs = raw_input('how many hours do you work per week:')
str_rate = raw_input('what is your rate per hour?:')
try:
    hrs = float(str_hrs)
    rate = float(str_rate)
except:
    print('enter a number, yo')    
else:
    if (hrs > 40.0):
        pay=2*hrs*rate
        print ('your weekly salary is: %0.2f') %pay
    else: 
        pay = hrs*rate
        print('your weekly salary is: %0.2f') %pay
```